# mule message.getInvocationProperty cannot be resolved from within Java method

Tags: java, mule

I'm trying to access a mule flowVar from within a Java class:

In the mule processor:
**flowVars.rootFilePath="c:\test"**

From within the mule processor, I'm calling the java method **renameFile(oldFile, newFile)** :

package com.rename;

import java.io.File;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;

public class FileRename {

```
public String renameFile(String oldFile, String newFile) {
    File file1 = new File(message.getInvocationProperty("rootFilePath") + oldFile);
    File file2 = new File(message.getInvocationProperty("rootFilePath") + newFile);
    file1.renameTo(file2);
    return "Renaming " + oldFile + " to: " + newFile;
}
```

}

However, I'm receiving the error "**message** cannot be resolved".  What am I missing here? Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: surely related to variable scoping. debug that line and check message's value

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `onCall` Method to do this?

You can use below code as a sample to access message.

```
public class MyComponent implements Callable {
 @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
     String oldFile = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty('');
      return "Renaming " + oldFile + " to: " + newFile;";
    }

}
```